# "Error to send message: Failed to fetch" using NextJS and Fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

I using fetch and NextJS. I trying to send name, phone, email, phone, company and message for a API from company and I can't do that because of this error and console error just send Failed to fetch and doesn't tell me what do

```
function submitContact() {
    let nome = document.getElementById('nome').value
    let email = document.getElementById('email').value
    let telefone = document.getElementById('telefone').value
    let nome_empresa = document.getElementById('empresa').value
    let mensagem = document.getElementById('mensagem').value

    let submit = {
        nome: nome,
        email: email,
        telefone: telefone,
        nome_empresa: nome_empresa,
        mensagem: mensagem
    }

    fetch('API_URL', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(submit)
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!')
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            alert('Erro ao enviar mensagem: ' + error)
        })
}
```

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of the failed error? Or at least post the response error with the http code.

Comment: I just send a alert using console.log `alert(console.log(error)` and the error is: "Failed to send message: Failed to fetch" only it.

Comment: Please don't use alert to debug, use the console in the development tools of your browser.  

Here's how to access them:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/

https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_console/index.html

Comment: When I use console.log, he doesn't works. I use the network console to see what's the problem with the fetch and found a cancel status when I try to send a email. The fix is to preventDefault on form and he's works, because everytime when I submit the form he's cancel the operation and refresh the page (that's the point).

Thanks for your patience and problem fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Added `<form action="" onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>` fix the problem.

The problem is because every submit cancel the fetch and refresh the page. With preventDefault I can hold that and work the process.